# highcharts - showing labels AND tickPositions

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a line graph using highcharts and I want to show all the labels AND a custom tickPosition yet I can either get it to show one or the other.

Labels:

[image]

tickPosition:

[image]

But what i really need is both. Here is a jsfiddle to fork / play with: (uncomment out the lines to see the tickPosition in action)

http://bit.ly/1ve3ou0

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) Add a second X axis. Use the default ticks/labels on one, and add your custom tick/label to the other.

2) Use `plotLines` for the custom line.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines